# Strongest result yet about paths of a given length in digraph.

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I am studying a paper named "[Longest paths in digraphs](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579454)".

In this paper they proved that for a connected digraph having the in-degree of any vertex at least $h$ and the out-degree of any vertex at least $k$ we can find a directed path having $\min(n,h+k+2)$ vertices.

But the paper was written in 1981, so I was searching for a newer and stronger result that gives a sufficient condition on the **degrees** of the vertices of a digraph to find a directed path of a given length. I have been searching for a while but didn't find any, so is it still the strongest result? Or what is the strongest result now?

There is also a conjecture by [*Thomassen*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.105.8325&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that states

If a digraph $D$ has minimum indegree and outdegree at least $k$ and if any two vertices of $D$ are on a common circuit, then $D$ contains a circuit of length greater than or equal to $\min(2k,n)$.

Is this conjecture solved yet?

Comment: There is no "still". When mathematicians say that something is "best possible", that means that the result cannot be made any stronger. The result will not stop being best possible because mathematics is not going to change. (But you have to check what the assumptions are.)

Comment: You are right, I removed the result that they described as "best possible"? But how about the second result, is it the best possible? And is the conjecture solved?